# JPA vs Low Level Datastore on App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa

I am getting into App Engine development right now with Java and I am wondering what people think about using the low level api instead of JPA? I understand that JPA may make the solutions more portable in the future but I don't anticipate taking my code anywhere else.

Is it ok to use the low level api instead of JPA? I'm interested in hearing the pros/cons of each method.

Comment: It should be obvious that high-level API has many drawbacks derived from the "distance" from the actual low-level code. Despite that, it is my opinion that for the sake of clarity high-level APIs should always be preferred over low-level ones - at least as long as all requirements from the software being developed are met...

Answer (score 2):

I woud perfer a clear API like jdo over direct use of datastore
There are new article serie with nice examples form Google self at
http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2009/12/jpajdo-java-persistence-tips-year-in.html

Comment: I find the low-level API more "clear" than JDO, but +1 for the excellent link.

Answer (score 0):

Why choose one or the other? I would choose a higher level abstraction that's documented (JPA or JDO) and the low-level API where the high level abstraction falls short.

Keep in mind that the API still seems to be a work in progress so if you choose the low level API exclusively, be prepared to roll with the changes.

I found JDO to be easiest to work with and haven't had to resort to using the low-level API yet.